# Run a makkro from an temporary Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, temporary-files, comexception

I am writting a program that loads an excel from the resources folder, runs a makkro and saves the output of the makkro to a variable. But every time I try to run my makkro the programm tells me it could not find my file where the excel is located. Now I wonder if my program is able to reach the temporary file path or if anything different from this occured.

I think the problem here might be that coppying the excel deactivates the makkros and that I should activate them again after coppying it. If this is a realistic problem could someone explain to me how I can outrun this?

**EDIT**

It also seems like the code is able to read the temporary file. At least it finds the excel sheets. The only problem now still existing are the makkros.

```
    public void CreateCopyOfResourcesExcel()
    {
        //temporary filepath to read the excel
        tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

        //copy excel to this filepath
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, Properties.Resources.Vorlage_Sensoren);
        excelApp = new _Excel.Application();
    }



     private void button_WFx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(tempPath);
        excelSheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets["Tabelle2"];
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        //run measurement
        excelApp.Run("Vorlage_Sensoren.xlsm!readValue"); //<-- here comes the error (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)

        RunSensorExcel(); //this is the function where I wanted to save the values
        
        //close excel
        excelWorkbook.Close(false);
        excelApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem here was that I was trying to run the makkro with the old name of the Excel. But through creating a temporary one the name of the excel changed and the program didn't recognized the old one.

So I fixed the program with the following code:

```
        //get makkro name with the new temp name of the excel
        string makkroName = Path.GetFileName(tempPath) + "!readValue";
        excelApp.Run(makkroName);
```